# Why are particles instances in Blender rotated by default?

Tags: particles

It's counterintuitive to me that objects rendered through the particle (hair) system are rotated under default settings. what I'm talking about is shown in this image[image: Rotated particle instances]:

The object I made has the appropriate colors aligned to the XYZ axis, but the instanced objects are x-axis up.

Is there a reason for aligning objects in this way? Asset packs from Blendermarket (like the Realistic Nature Asset Pack) come with their objects lying on their side to compensate for this but I think ideally this shouldn't be necessary.

So is there a reason for why particles work in this way or is it just a quirk of Blender?

Comment: I think it's just one of those Blender quirks, perhaps it will be fixed in the future

Comment: I see. An impact of this choice is that the Geometry nodes instancing and particle system instancing do not use the source object rotation in the same way. It would be nice if this was more consistent.

Comment: Some legacy reason for this that I read once and could never find again.  Quick fix: select object to be used as a particle, and R, X, -90.  Apply rotation.